# Is it possible to return Singleton's value without executing it's methd?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have a singleton that looks like this

```
+(DataController*)sharedInstance
{
    static DataController *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate,
        ^{
            if (sharedInstance == nil)
            {
                sharedInstance = [[DataController alloc]init];
            }
        });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Now, I have a couple methods where it's return value depends on Singleton's sharedInstance value.

I want to do something like this:

```
DataController *nilInstance =  [DataController sharedInstance];

if (nilInstance == nil)
{
    // do this
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

When I run my application and it goes to this line

```
DataController *nilInstance =  [DataController sharedInstance];
```

It goes to my Singleton class and it runs the whole method and so it will never be nil. What could be an approach to this solution?

Comment: you've been already told in your previous question - the return value will never be nil. it's impossible. why do you want it to be nil?

Comment: There is an object that doesn't exist when the app is executed. Once the user starts interacting with the app, then this object is created and I want this object to be loaded when the user returns to the main screen.In case I don't use this "if" statement, the app does not crash or anything but I get a "CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null), or invalid scale factor: 2.000000" when the app is executed because the object hasn't been created.

Comment: so why not create this object on app's launch?

Comment: @Andrey Chernukha  This object is a UIImageView and the it is selected by the userlater on. I implemented this singleton because I want to pass this UIIMage to many other view controllers. The problem is when the user changes the UIImageView for another one and then go back to the MainViewController, then the new UIImageView is not displayed. I reload this by loading the view through the Singleton...

Comment: Instead of checking if nilInstance is nil you could check if nilInstance.imageView is nil.

Comment: @Edu you know what? post all your relevant code here. cause it seems you have all the stuff so much complicated and it's really difficult for me to understand what you're trying to do. I'm absolutely sure that your task may be implemented pretty easy. Post the code and we see if something may be done. But only the NEEDED code, not all your classes

Comment: @Edu You might want to consider deleting this question. The first effect is that the negative votes will come off of your reputation. The second effect is that the less helpful question will roll off the wiki. Removing a less helpful question is a win-win in this case. You will recover 8 reputation points and you could always take a shot at organizing a better question. Suggest you read the entire help section as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since It is a singleton class, It will return the same object every time where you will call this. You will not get nil. Why do you want to get nil if you are using singleton class.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it simple. I have another class that creates an object that is displayed on the screen but it is created later and then singleton will hold this object. So when the app is executed the app is trying to load this object through the singleton which does not exist yet. that is why I wanted it to be nil.

Answer (score 0):

The point of creating a shared instance is to access the singleton instance of class throughout the application. When you first run the code singleton is created and it persist throughout the app life cycle as it is defined as static. This method will never return nil.